# Upstream server always redirects back to root path in Nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, pgadmin-4

I plan to run an [pgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/) instance behind Nginx reverse proxy.

What I want is requests coming to `http://myhost.com/pgadmin4` should be forwarded to upstream `http://localhost:8087` where pgAdmin is listening.

To achieve this, I followed [this nginx.conf recipe](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/6.14/container_deployment.html#http-via-nginx) from pgAdmin's official doc. Here's the snippet:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myhost.com;

    location /pgadmin4/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /pgadmin4;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8087/;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Everything works fine except that after successful login, the server sends HTTP 301 response with location header sets to root path (i.e. `"Location: /"`) aand bam, user agent is redirected to http://myhost.com/ where nothing is waiting (except nginx default page, for now).

Retyping the url to http://myhost.com/pgadmin4/ is still okay. The user agent's state, cookies and all are all set and user can continue as normal. It's just that it's a mild annoyance for end users having to retype the whole URL again.

I know that I can alter upstream's HTTP redirect response by using [`proxy_redirect`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) directive, but I can't figure out what the value should be.

Is what I'm trying to do achievable from just by Nginx configuration? Is there any specific PgAdmin4 config that I need to change?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same exact problem and I have not been able to solve it.